# ggplot cuts off axis labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

how do I avoid that ggplot cuts off axis labels such as in this example, where the % Symbol isn't shown?

[image]

Comment: `+ coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`

Comment: somehow this doesn't change anything

Comment: Then please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: you can "expand" your axis ends, i.e. + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.1,0.1))

Answer (score 0):

Set `x=element_blank()` in `theme()`

```
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```