# RMarkdown and ggplot: Axis labels cut off

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, r-markdown

In an RMarkdown PDF document, I am generating a heatmap with rather long tick labels. For some reason, this causes the y-axis label and the colour legend to be cut off. I already attempted several tricks in order to fix this, but so far to no avail. Here is my reprex:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
draft: true
  
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = FALSE, fig_crop=FALSE
)
```

```{r dependencies, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
options(print_format="tex")
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
# Dummy data
set.seed(1234)
Count = rep((1:5), 8)
Gadget = rep(c("BANANA", "APPLE", "PEAR", "ORANGE", "ENCYCLOPEDIA", "XYLOPHONE", "TOMATO", "POTATO"), each=5)
GadgetScore = runif(40, 0, 100)
data = data.frame(Count, Gadget, GadgetScore)
```

```{r}
# Generate heatmap
maxi = max(data$GadgetScore, na.rm=TRUE)
mini = min(data$GadgetScore, na.rm=TRUE)
midi = mini+(maxi-mini)/2
ggplot(data, aes(Count, Gadget, fill=GadgetScore)) + geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient2(name="Gadget score value", low="red", mid="yellow", high="green", midpoint=midi) +
  labs(x="Count", y="Gadgets")
```
````

Here is the output:
[image: Heatmap with cropped axis labels and color legend]

As you can see, the y-axis label *Gadgets* on the left hand side, and the colour legend label *Gadget score value* on the right hand side are cropped. As I said, I already tried a couple of hints from StackOverflow, but so far, none of them worked.

**Trick 1:** Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67385667/5363942), I tried adding

```
theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank())
```

to the `ggplot` elements.

**Trick 2:** Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44396858/5363942), I tried to adapt the width of the plot chunk with something like

```
fig.width = 5
```

**Trick 3:** Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32924926), I tried adding

```
theme(plot.margin = margin(100, 100, 100, 100))
```

to the `ggplot` elements.

**Trick 4:** I tried adding the option `crop = FALSE` and `fig_crop=FALSE` to the setup chunk.

Unfortunately, none of these tricks worked. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the figure size in the chunk options? e.g. `{r, fig.width = 8, fig.height = 8}`.

Comment: I did your code and the result was perfectly fine! I did not modify anything

Comment: @teunbrand Thank you for your reply! I already tried this (Trick 2), but it didn't work.

Comment: @elielink Thank you! This could mean that it is merely an issue of package or R versions. I will check it on a different system and let you know.

Comment: I checked it on another system and the result was flawless. However, both systems use the same R-version 4.0.5, the system with the cropped output is a linux server with pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021), the system with flawless output is Windows 10 machine with pdfTeX Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX). I will try updating all packages on the linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the cropping error was related to a deprecated version of GhostScript. After updating GhostScript to the latest version (9.54.0), I can run the reprex without any image cropping issues.

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly for me. However, you can check the alignment of the image, maybe if you place it a bit more to the right you can see the label. For this try in the last chunk to add `{r, fig.dim = c(5, 2.5), fig.align = 'right'}`